# is there any way to make System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(string) look in the program's directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, io, tilde-expansion

I'm trying to use  `string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("~/Pictures/");` to search a folder in the program for picture files. This will later be used to randomly select a picture to display in an image box.I get an error when it tries to find ~/Pictures because the method is looking in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\~\Pictures\'. instead. Isn't the "~" going to make it look in the programs directory? How do I make it look in the programs directory if I don't know what it will be until the program is installed? Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719293/defining-a-working-directory-for-executing-a-program-c

Comment: @kenny what? I think you might have forgotten a link

Comment: yes, but you must have slipped in there I added it 10 second or less later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tilde path is an asp.net construct that represents the root of the currently running asp.net application. It has no meaning outside of the asp.net context -- Directory.GetFiles doesn't know how to work with it. GetFiles *does* know how to work with a regular filesystem path. So the question becomes: How do we translate the asp.net relative path to one GetFiles can work with. The answer is [HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx).

I'm not near my webserver right now, but something like

```
var serverPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Pictures/");
var files = Directory.GetFiles(serverPath);
```

should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find the "~" has any significance.

Try Application.StartupPath

Comment: +1. StartupPath and `Path.Combine` to construct path. (`"~" is "folder for root of the site" in the ASP.Net world...)

Answer (score 0):

Supplying a relative directory, like "Pictures", instead of "~/Pictures/", should do the trick.

Comment: still same problem, its looking in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0

Answer (score 0):

Just use `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles('Pictures')`. The path separator on Windows is `\`, not `/`, and directories below the current one are just referenced as relative path locations.

Comment: if you use \ in a string it is seen as an escape sequence

Comment: @Craig: Then you escape it (`\\`).

Comment: ok, / works for this line Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Pictures/" imageNumber + ".jpg";