# How to import new font family in dotnet c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a custom font .ttf file specified in a folder on my project. I want to import that specific font into Fontfamily function.

I have tried this:

```
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("/myfontpath/fontname.ttf");
```

and this:

```
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("/myfontpath/fontname.ttf#font name");
```

but those do not seem to solve the problem. The output i received was **Font "/myfontpath/fontname.ttf"** cannot be found.

How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: starting with a "/" means it will start searching in the root folder, not your project folder

Comment: isn't root folder a project folder?

Comment: the root of the current hard drive. i.e. "C:\" if on windows, or simply "/" on unix

Comment: Generally best to determine the full path. removing the slash will usually work...depending on how the app is run.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719293/defining-a-working-directory-for-executing-a-program-c

Comment: should I change "C:\" and put the full path instead then?

Comment: As a first check to see whether the font works, you can put in the full path. But for the final program you don't want to depend on a specific hardcoded location. So find a way to get the path relative to your application (or maybe use an "embedded resource")