# How do you set the "Start in" folder for an application using the MSIX "Windows Application Packaging Project"

Tags: windows-store, msix, windows-application-packaging

I have an application which reads a file from its *own* programs files folder; The application assumes it get's started in that specific folder, the local current directory. (Currently it crashes, as the file is required, and not found).

> Current directory: C:\Windows\system32
>
> Error reading file f.dat

Using other Installers like `Wix` and `InnoSetup` one can create the shortcuts, with their specific `start in` folders.

How do solve this? Is it possible to set the `start in` folder for the Application, using the Visual Studio `Windows Application Packaging Project`, which generates the `MSIX` installer.

*I am thinking of determining the install folder at runtime, and then to read the file using an absolute path.
Perhaps there is some documented registry entry I should query.*

Comment: "I am thinking of determining the install folder at runtime" -- if you can change the application, just use `GetModuleFileName(NULL)` to find the application filename and start from there.

Comment: Similar problem with the one described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76451425/msix-publish-loading-xml-config-file-not-working/76465361#76465361

You seem to be on the right track with the solution you adopted.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not rely on the "start in" folder, but to use the path  of the running process.

In my specific case I am using `Go` (Golang). Using [os.Executable()](https://go.dev/src/os/executable.go)

Here is my old code which failed when using `MSIX`:

```
// read using current directory 
cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
log.Printf("current directory: %s", cwd)

b, err := os.ReadFile(fName)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("error reading file %s", fName)
}
return b
```

And the new code:

```
// read using starting process directory 
exePath, err := os.Executable()
if err == nil {
    // strip executable name from path 
    exePath = strings.ReplaceAll(exePath, "AppName.exe", "")
    fullPath := fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", exePath, fName)

    // read file
    log.Printf("reading: %s\n", fullPath)
    b, err := os.ReadFile(fullPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed reading %s : %v\n",fName, err)
    }
    return b
}
```